# Why is a FetchContent using a different TAG than the one I specified? How can I resolve this?

Tags: git, cmake, git-tag, fetchcontent

I am trying to use a certain library with FetchContent:

```
FetchContent_Declare(
    Catch2
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2.git
    GIT_TAG        3f0283de7a9c43200033da996ff9093be3ac84dc
    GIT_PROGRESS   TRUE
    GIT_SHALLOW    FALSE
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(Catch2)
```

According to practice I am specifying a particular tag.
However when I look at the files that cmake downloads, the tag is `7cf2f88e50f0d1de324489c31db0314188423b6d` instead, and it is older (Feb 14 2023).

If I manually got to `_deps/catch2-src` and do `git checkout 3f0283de7a9c43200033da996ff9093be3ac84dc`, I get the correct version (Jun 21 2023).

What is wrong with the FetchContent block above? Why would CMake download the incorrect or older version of the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My top suspect is

> The `FetchContent_Declare()` function records the options that describe how to populate the specified content. **If such details have already been recorded earlier in this project (regardless of where in the project hierarchy), this and all later calls for the same content  are ignored.**

Comment: It took me a while to understand that this means that multiple calls to FetchContent, even in the dependencies could cause this problem. _Is there a way to avoid this?_ I know, I should be using a package manager, but still, this behavior without a warning or an error is very confusing.

Comment: About as far from a cmake guru as you can get, put a prefix on all your names would be my first attempt. `alfC` or maybe the project name, `alfC-Catch2`.

Comment: @jthill that can be a solution if you have version conflict problems. but otherwise, you'd just be opting out of software reuse in possibly costly ways.

Answer (score 1):

From [the FetchContent docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html):

> The `FetchContent_Declare()` function records the options that describe how to populate the specified content. **If such details have already been recorded earlier in this project (regardless of where in the project hierarchy), this and all later calls for the same content  are ignored.**

If a previous call to `FetchContent_Declare` for the same name (in this case `Catch2`) chose a different `TAG`, the first one of those calls that sets `TAG` will "win". Are there any other calls to `FetchContent_Declare` for Catch2 anywhere in the configuration? Perhaps in one of your dependencies (if you have any)? If you don't want to search manually, you can use [`cmake --trace`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-trace) and then `grep` or `jq` for `FetchContent_Declare` calls.

This whole business is by design. From the same docs:

> Projects should aim to declare the details of all dependencies they might use before they call `FetchContent_MakeAvailable()` for any of them. This ensures that if any of the dependencies are also sub-dependencies of one or more of the others, the main project still controls the details that will be used (because it will declare them first before the dependencies get a chance to)

Once you find the thing that's taking precendence, just move things around in your CMakeLists.txt so that your call to `FetchContent_Declare` goes first so it "wins".

If your call to `FetchContent_Declare` for a given name is the only one for that name, then you shouldn't have this problem. Even if you change the commitish being referenced in the `TAG` argument of your call, the next time your run configuration, CMake will update the checkout to that new commitish. And if you run build without reconfiguring, CMake is usually smart enough at knowing when it needs to reconfigure to do it automatically.

Comment: This seems hard to solve if I don't control de dependency which also calls FetchContent for a different TAG. Maybe I am doing it all wrong.

Comment: @alfC move your `FetchContent_Declare` to go before the place where you register that dependency / make it available. See also the edit I just made to my answer.